# Strange php if behaviour with casted to boolean int

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

let's see if somebody can help me.

I have function called ret_error() which is called when there's an error accessing a table in a database, that means, "could not connect", "record not found" and this like that. This functions returns an array with two keys like this

```
array('error' => true, 'code' => Model::RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
```

If I call a function that returns an array built with ret_error() and I inspect the array it is like

```
$result = array('error' => 1, 'code' => Model::RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
```

But when I evaluate with an 'if'

```
if (!$result['error']) {
   do something;
}
else {
   do something else;
}
```

Always is evaluated as false even if I cast to a boolean.

This works correctly if evaluated as int such as

```
if ($result['error'] != 1) {
```

Is there something I'm missing?.

Comment: What about `if($result['error'] === true)`? this way three `===` will force to be totally equal. As you know `0` is interpreted as `false` and `1` as `true` in programming.

Answer (score 0):

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

In short, 0 is False and all other values is True
I would suggest a quick hack

```
if($result['error'] === true || $result['error'] === 1) {
   //logic
}
```

Comment: I cannot refrain from saying this, even though is OT. PHP is stupid: "the empty string, and the string '0'"! I so very hate that... What the hekk, why on earth is the non empty string "0" a false? That has always bugged me... P.S: I'm a PHP developer since PHP4, I can say PHP is stupid :-)

Comment: lol, good point from you. I still think they probably have a good historical reason to make it works that way. 
Meanwhile, integer 0 is False so it would make more sense to have string "0" to be False as well. Otherwise, if you cast a int 0 to string "0", you basically transform it from False to True (this may cause confusion).

Comment: I partly agree with you, but from my personal experience the only recurrent bug I stumbled upon was someone checking a string inside a conditional statement (i.e. checking if an input was provided) and you can't blame the junior developer for non using `if (strlen($string)) ...` instead of `if ($string) ...`, I blame the language! :-)